# Jsonix-schema-compiler cannot convert .xsd file to JSON Object

Tags: json, xml, xsd, jsonix

I converted a few .xsd files to a JSON Object with the [jsonix-schema-compiler](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler), but there is one .xsd with qualified namespaces.

The following .xsd cannot be converted - there is no error message, but also no output is generated. I tried to switch the logoutput to TRACE, but that does not help, because it just outputs nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:lost1" xmlns:p2="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ns1="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:lost1">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="p2.xsd"/>
      <xs:element name="findService">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="ns1:location"/>
                  <xs:element ref="ns1:service"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="recursive" use="required" type="xs:boolean"/>
              <xs:attribute name="serviceBoundary" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
           </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="location">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="p2:Point"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
              <xs:attribute name="profile" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
           </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="service" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
 </xs:schema>
```

Any ideas why this can't be converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without trying it out. Please send me a pull request with a reproducing test case:

https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-support/

Here's an example of such a test project:

https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-support/tree/master/s/shiporder

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix).

Comment: Thank you. Just solved it. The PR from yesterday was mine.